# How to transfer object value to modal class using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm having a hard time passing the value of an object to a model.

I wanted to pass the data from this obj to the model class

```
 SingleTransactResponse obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleTransactResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());               

SaveTransaction(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

I used this function to get the data from the model and save it to the database

```
PayoutEntities payoutdb = new PayoutEntities();

public String SaveTransaction(payout_transaction model)
        {

            payoutdb.payout_transaction.Add(model);
            payoutdb.SaveChanges();
            return "Success";
        }
```

SingleTransactResponse Class

```
public class SingleTransactResponse {
        public String senderRefId { get; set; }
        public String tranRequestDate { get; set; }
        public String particulars { get; set; }
        public List<Beneficiary> beneficiary { get; set; }
}
```

Beneficiary Class

```
public class Beneficiary
    {
        public String accountNumber { get; set; }

        public String name { get; set; }

        public List<Address> address { get; set; }
    }
```

Address Class

```
public class Address
    {
        public String line1 { get; set; }

        public String line2 { get; set; }

        public String city { get; set; }

        public String province { get; set; }

        public String zipCode { get; set; }

        public String country { get; set; }
    }
```

payout_transaction class

```
public partial class payout_transaction
 {
        public string transid { get; set; }
        public string batchid { get; set; }
        public string senderRefId { get; set; }
        public string requestDate { get; set; }
        public string benefName { get; set; }
        public string benefacctno { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string errdesc { get; set; }
        public string transaction_fee { get; set; }
}
```

I'm just having a hard time converting the obj to the model. I've tried `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)` but it only converts it to string. Is there any possible way to do this or any work around to solve this problem?

Comment: payout_transaction is a model class? if yes then you need to manually create a instance and pass it on

Comment: yes it is,but can you tell me how should i do that?

Comment: can you post the SingleTransacResponse  class and payout_transaction  class (with properties)

Comment: I've already edited my question and post the classes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
var payoutModel = new payout_transaction
{
   senderRefId = obj.senderRefId,
   requestDate = obj.tranRequestDate,
   .... other properties
}

SaveTransaction(payoutModel);
```